# Как я могу конвертировать объект Styler в байты?

Tags: python, pandas

Я пробовал `bytes(pdf)`, где pdf это объект Styler, но у меня возникала ошибка - `TypeError: cannot convert 'Styler' object to bytes`. Есть ли другой способ конвертации объекта Styler в байты?

Comment: а зачем нужна подобная конвертация?

Comment: @MaxU Например для отправки на сервер, который принимает только байты. Почему не сохранять его с помощью `.to_excel()` и потом просто не читать его с помощью `with open('filename.xlsx') as file: file.read()` - Потому что я не хочу, чтобы файл сохранялся на диске.

Comment: на диск сохранять не обязательно - почитайте о [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала я преобразовал `Styler` в `DataFrame` с помощью `pdf = pdf.data`. Далее, чтобы получить байты из этого `DataFrame` я применил эти методы:

```
to_records()
tostring()
```

То есть у меня получилось это:

```
pdf = pdf.data
pdf = pdf.to_records().tostring()
```